# HTTP 401 Fog::Storage::Rackspace::ServiceError

Tags: carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4, fog

I am working to get with Rails 4 / Ruby 2  fog / carrierwave  integration. Basically I have in my app after around a day of the unicorn servers running it is returning: [HTTP 401] Fog::Storage::Rackspace::ServiceError
I then query the server, and check if I can manually hit the server, and have no issues.
So I am very lost and what to do.

```
F, [2013-06-17T00:47:58.519007 #31200] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error ([HTTP 401] Fog::Storage::Rackspace::ServiceError):
21:             <li class="span4">
22:               <div class="thumbnail">
23:                 <div style="height: 270px">
24:                   <%= image_tag(website.logo_url(:web), :class => 'img-rounded') if website.logo? %>
25:                 </div>
```

Today I saw that they updated FOG to 1.12.1 and am trying to upgrade, but I really don't know what the issue is. It almost seems as though the connection to Rackspace goes bad.... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Henning's observations, I was able to find that Fog's Rackspace CDN service was not re-authenticating after the authentication token expired. I have submitted the following pull request to fog => https://github.com/fog/fog/pull/1899.

I expect a new version of Fog to be released in early July with this fix. In the interim, I have created a patch to be applied to the current Fog gem -> https://gist.github.com/krames/5817816

This file should be saved in the initializer's directory of your rails application and named 01_cdn_patch.rb in order for it to be properly applied. It will only work for Fog 1.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue. The AuthToken expires after 24 hours. When this happens fog raises this error and did not try to reauthenticate. If you restart the server Fog reauthenticates. But that's doesn't count as a solution.

Hope you will figure out some solution. I added the relevant stack trace. We use fog 1.12.1.

```
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:10:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:353:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:247:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:25:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/rackspace/cdn.rb:157:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/rackspace/requests/cdn/head_container.rb:30:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/rackspace/cdn.rb:62:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/rackspace/models/storage/directory.rb:183:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/rackspace/models/storage/directory.rb:131:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/rackspace/models/storage/file.rb:177:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:304:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:322:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/url.rb:19:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:160:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/default_url.rb:8:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:156:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/default_url.rb:8:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:377:in `'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:187:in `'
```

Comment: Henning, your details definitely helped! Looking through the Fog CDN code, to reauthenticate after after a HTTP 401 like the storage service. Let me try to submit a pull request with a fix for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it using gem "fog", "~> 1.14.0"in the Gemfile rather than gem "fog", "~> 1.10.1" as this page recommends https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-rackspace-cloud-files